Extending getFeatureInfo with (custom) metadata of a GeoServer WMS endpoint
I am trying to add metadata to a getFeatureInfo request return of a GeoServer instance (any recent version… 2.24.4 or later using the Kartoza docker). I added a content.ftl to the configuration and this works as expected:
    <caption class="featureInfo">${type.name}</caption><br />
    <caption class="featureInfo">${type.namespace}</caption>

But this does not:
    <caption class="featureInfo">${type.abstract}</caption><br />

Is there a way to add other metadata fields to the html getFeatureInfo request return?
What other metadata fields are available?
Is it possible to add custom metadata fields using the metadata plugin?
How can these custom fields be accessed?

Does it make sense to add layer information to a feature response? Why not look it up once and add it to the getfeatureinfo results

Good point, but how do you look it up once? It would still have to come from the metadata attached to the layer, no? I was thinking of either using the "abstract" of a layer or layer group for this or to use the metadata plugin to add a custom metadata field to every layer.

You can read the capabilities to find out about a layer.

Thanks Ian, we implemented this in the way you suggest via the getCapabilities, for coverage stores available via e.g.: http://{geoserver_instance}/geoserver/rest/workspaces/{workspace}/coveragestores/{coveragestore}/coverages/{coveragename}.json (or .xml). Is it possible to add this info to the getFeatureInfo? Via the content.ftl template?
